# Exchange anagement Shell catch enable-mailbox error

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2010, emc

I have script that creates user accounts and establishes an e-mail address for those accounts. All 'create-commands' are surrounded by a try/catch block to catch errors and add a message to the output log. This works fine... except for the enable-mailbox command

```
try { 
    Enable-Maibox (.. parameters ...) 
}
catch {
    $errorsEncountered = $true
    Write-Output "Error establishing e-mail address for $($UserData.username)"
}
```

when the enable-mailbox command fails... the catch-part is skipped. Why is this? And how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-termineting errors are not catched. Use '-ErrorAction Stop' to make the errors terminating errors.

```
Enable-Maibox (.. parameters ...) -ErrorAction Stop
```

Comment: but won't that stop the script entirely? I don't want it to stop, only to report the error and carry on with the next instruction.

Comment: No, it will not stop your script but enter your catch as desired.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but "Enable-Maibox" looks mis-spelled.

Comment: The accepted answer seems to have answered the question, despite the misspelling. Perhaps the code was typed in by hand. In any case, this was answered several years ago.